# how to rotate VerticalfieldManager at 180 degrees in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, rotation

```java
vf=new VerticalFieldManager()
{
    public void paint(Graphics graphics)
    {
        int theta = Fixed32.toFP(180);
        int cell_11 = Fixed32.cosd(theta);
        int cell_12 = -Fixed32.sind(theta);
        int cell_21 = Fixed32.sind(theta);
        int cell_22 = Fixed32.cosd(theta);

        int[] rotate = new int[] 
                { cell_11, cell_12,
                  0, 0,
                  cell_21, cell_22,
                };

        super.paint(graphics);
        myFont = Font.getDefault().derive(Font.PLAIN, 0, 
                                          DrawStyle.HCENTER, Font.BOLD, 
                                          0, rotate);
        vf.setFont(myFont );            
    }
};
```

Comment: What exactly do you need to rotate, the background or the text? If it's the text, try calling `graphics.setFont` before the super call, instead of the 2 last lines.

Comment: hi Smith, thanks actually i want to rotate complete VerticalFieldManager at 180 degrees. it is possible or not?

Comment: can any one help me?? thanks in advance